# Is there a way in Excel to take a column and convert it to a concatenated string

Tags: excel, concatenation

I want to take a list of names that are in multiple rows and combined them into a single cell like this:

Joe
Bob
George

and convert that into one cell that has this:

"Joe", "Bob", "George"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the [Excel `CONCATENATE()` function](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/concat.php) won't do what you want, [this link](http://bytes.com/topic/misc/answers/781572-excel-concatenate-range) might help.

Comment: Answered this question with a question.

Comment: If the links die this answer becomes almost useless

Answer (score 7):

Try using TRANSPOSE function and pressing F9 on it:

```
+---+--------+
|   |   A    |
+---+--------+
| 1 | Joe    |
| 2 | Bob    |
| 3 | George |
+---+--------+
```

B1: (type in function bar)

```
=TRANSPOSE(A1:A3)
```

Highlight TRANSPOSE(A1:A3), and press <kbd>F9</kbd>.

It will give you:

```
{"Joe","Bob","George"}
```

Copy and paste that list. That's it.

**To concatenate the words, you just have to do:**

```
=CONCATENATE(TRANSPOSE(A1:A3))
```

Highlight `TRANSPOSE(A1:A3)`, press <kbd>F9</kbd>, then remove the brackets:

```
=CONCATENATE("Joe","Bob","George")
```

Answer (score 3):

There are two basic ways that I know of.

Quickest way -

1. Column A lists your names

   Copy the value of A1 to B1 - "Joe"

   In B2, enter the formula `=B1 & ", " & A2`

   Select B2, Copy the formula, and paste down the rest of column B the entire length of column A.  The last cell in column B will contain a comma separated list of values from column A.

Better way - 
Make your own vb function that iterates across a range of cells, and instead of summing them like `sum`, just concatenate them.

I do this all the time, so if anyone knows of an actual built-in Excel function buried somewhere in MS documentation that concatenates ranges, you will save the day.

Answer (score 2):

Add this as a macro to the Excel sheet and use it as a custom function with range and delimiter as input

```
Function Concat(myRange As Range, Optional myDelimiter As String) As String
  Dim r As Range
  Application.Volatile
  For Each r In myRange
    If Len(r.Text) Then
      Concat = Concat & IIf(Concat <> "", myDelimiter, "") & r.Text
    End If
  Next
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

It is this easy.  You might want to use in combination with trim, left, right, and find.  Enjoy!

`= A1 & " " & B1`

Answer (score 0):

You can use GetString with an ADO recordset.

```
Dim cn As Object
Dim rs As Object
Dim strFile As String
Dim strCon As String
Dim strSQL As String
Dim s As String

''This is not the best way to refer to the workbook
''you want, but it is very conveient for notes
''It is probably best to use the name of the workbook.

strFile = ActiveWorkbook.FullName

strCon = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & strFile _
    & ";Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=No;IMEX=1"";"

Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

cn.Open strCon

strSQL = "SELECT * " _
       & "FROM [Sheet1$A:A] "

rs.Open strSQL, cn, 3, 3

''http://www.w3schools.com/ado/ado_getstring.asp
''str = rs.GetString(format,rows,coldel,rowdel,nullexpr)
s = rs.GetString(, , , ", ")
ActiveSheet.Range("B1") = s

''Tidy up
rs.Close
Set rs = Nothing
cn.Close
Set cn = Nothing
```